# Hey I want to use Intent object everything is fine but when I click on submit it is not opening map app

Tags: android, android-intent, resolveactivity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3"));
if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I Tried this [ScreenShot of Adnroid studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuPHl.png)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3"));
  if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
  {
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Expecting to let me move to map app but not working

Comment: For `resolveActivity()` to work on Android 11+, you will need to [handle package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring). It will be simpler to remove the `resolveActivity()` call and wrap your `startActivity()` call in a `try`/`catch`, then do something if you catch an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 47.6, -122.3);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Try above code